# Why does plotting a PolyLog function yield 1/0 error? (Intentional bug?)

Tags: plotting, bugs, warning-messages, special-functions, version-11

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and fixed in 11.1.1**

---

In *Mathematica* 11.0, the following

```
Plot[Re[PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - x)]], {x, -3, 3}]
```

generates a `Power::infy` message before displaying the plot.  I asked WRI about this [CASE:3810816], and the support representative told me that

> The developer said the generated Power message is by design.

Since `Plot[1/(1 - x), {x, -3, 3}]` does not generate a similar error, I find this a little inconsistent?

Is there a rationale for intentionally introducing a bug in `Plot`?

Comment: It' s related to [`Exclusions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Exclusions).Try using ``Exclusions->None``.

Comment: @CarlWoll I don't understand that.  Why doesn't `Plot[1/(1 - x), {x, -3, 3}]` or even `Plot[Re[Log[1/(1 - x)]], {x, -3, 3}]` generate errors?

Comment: I don't have any knowledge about the internals of Exclusions, but we can assume that it is looking for a singularity of the expression. The code to find this singularity must depend on the expression, and finding singularities of an arbitrary function must involve evaluating it, possibly at the point of singularity. Presumably your other examples are common enough that function evaluations are not required.

Comment: @CarlWoll - `Exclusions -> 1` also eliminates the warning message and strikes me as easier to understand than `Exclusions -> None`

Comment: @BobHanlon Exclusions->2 also eliminates the warning message. Basically, Exclusions->rhs eliminates automatic exclusion detection unless rhs contains Automatic. It is the automatic exclusion detection code that is issuing messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To explain the difference between the OP's and [QuantumDot's comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140855/why-does-plotting-a-polylog-function-yield-1-0-error-intentional-bug#comment380534_140855) examples, consider the V11 automatic exclusions expansions:

```
Visualization`ExpandExclusions[Re[PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - x)]], {x}, Automatic]  (* OP *)
Visualization`ExpandExclusions[Re[Log[1/(1 - x)]], {x}, Automatic]         (* comment *)
(*
  {{Im[1/(1 - x)] == 0, Re[1/(1 - x)] >= 1}, {1 - x == 0, True}, {1/(1 - x) == 1, True}}
  {{Im[1/(1 - x)] == 0, Re[1/(1 - x)] <= 0}, {1 - x == 0, True}, {False, True}}
*)
```

The first two discontinuities are the same, but the third is different.  Moreover, in the OP's case, the third evaluates to `1/0` at the discontinuity `x == 1`.  This seems to be source of the error message.  This could probably be considered a bug, but if you've been around *Mathematica* long enough, you probably remember when `Plot` was always giving `Pwer::infy` messages.

Some tests follow below. The `{False, True}` in the comment version `ex2` is perhaps not a valid exclusion spec, as it seems to turn off exclusions.  The third set of exclusions `ex3` will show that it is the interaction between the last two exclusions in the OP's `PolyLog` example that leads to the error.

```
ex1 = {{Im[1/(1 - x)] == 0, Re[1/(1 - x)] >= 1}, {1 - x == 0, True}, {1/(1-x) == 1,True}};
ex2 = {{Im[1/(1 - x)] == 0, Re[1/(1 - x)] >= 1}, {1 - x == 0, True}(*, {False, True}*)};
ex3 = {{Im[1/(1 - x)] == 0, Re[1/(1 - x)] >= 1}, {1/(1-x) == 1,True}};
```

Using the `PolyLog` exclusions generates `1/0.` errors; using the `Log` exclusions generates no errors:

```
Plot[Re[Log[1/(1 - x)]], {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> ex1]         (* 1/0. error *)
Plot[Re[PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - x)]], {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> ex2]  (* no error *)
Plot[Re[PolyLog[2, 1/(1 - x)]], {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> ex3]  (* no error *)
Plot[1/(1 - x), {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> ex1]                  (* 1/0. error *)
```

Some functions must be white-listed:

```
Plot[x, {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> ex2]                          (* no error *)
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> ex2]                     (* no error *)
```

But the discontinuity does not have to be at `x == 1`, for the OP's exclusions to generate a `1/0.` error:

```
Plot[Tan[x], {x, -3, 3}, Exclusions -> ex1]                     (* 1/0. error *)
```

As for a rationale justifying the error message in plotting `PolyLog[]`, I am at a loss.

Comment: This is very helpful and enlightening.  So, would you this behaviour a bug?

Comment: @QuantumDot As a bug, it's not an error per se (the end result is correct and apparently 1 is divided by 0), but, OTOH, it's unwanted, unhelpful, and unnecessary. If it were *my* software product, I would say it's a bug because it irritates the customers for no good reason.

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to extend the automatic `Exclusions` computation by informing it of all the singularities in a user-derived functions of the form `f[x_?NumericQ]:=...`?  That would be most useful, especially in building packages for the numerical evaluation of special functions.