# Plot & StreamPlot eat my Messages

Tags: plotting, message-coding

I have a complicated function for `StreamPlot` to call that includes some error checking and the use of `Message`.  Somehow the messages are not displayed when the function is called from `StreamPlot`.  Here's a toy example:

Define the function & message:

```
f[x_] := Module[{},
  If[x > 1, Print["print: ", x]; Message[f::msg, x]];
  x];

f::msg = "`1` is greater than 1";
```

Test it by itself:

```
f[1.2]
(* print: 1.2 *)
(* f::msg f:1.2` is greater than 1 *)
(* 1.2 *)
```

Works as expected, but put it in a `StreamPlot` and only the `Print`ed messages are shown:

```
StreamPlot[{f[x], y}, {x, 0, 1.2}, {y, 0, 1}]
(* txt: 1.22403 *)
(* txt: 1.22403 *)
(* ... *)
```

How can I get those `Messages` to show?

**Update:**

`Plot` eats `Messages` too.

Comment: Oddly, it does not eat one of the messages [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/140855/why-does-plotting-a-polylog-function-yield-1-0-error-intentional-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reset `$Messages`.

```
f[x_] := Module[{}, 
   If[x > 1, Print["print: ", x]; 
    Block[{$Messages = Streams["stdout"]},
     If[! ListQ@$MessageList, $MessageList = {}];
     Message[f::msg, x]]];
   x];
```

`$MessageList` should be a list, which if is not when `f` is called. Just what to do about it, whether to `Block` it too or reset it globally as above, I am not completely sure.  It worked both ways with the following plot:

```
Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 1.01}]
```

Comment: Thanks! Seems like I will need to replace a lot of calls to `Message` with something like this. Could this be wrapped into a plug-and-play function with identical syntax to `Message`? Also, would you consider this a bug to report to WRI?

Comment: In response to my first question in the previous comment, seems so.  Will add as a separate answer later tonight.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to wrap up @MichaelE2's trick into a plug-and-play replacement for `Message`:

```
Msg[msgs__] := Block[{$Messages = Streams["stdout"]},
  If[!ListQ@$MessageList, $MessageList = {}];
  Message[msgs];
];
SetAttributes[Msg, HoldAll];
```

This seems to work except it usually overrules `General::stop` in `Plot` and `StreamPlot`, which I can live with.